# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:80

Tags: android

I have Wampp PHP server on my local computer (127.0.0.1:80). I am making a android login app that is connecting to mysql server. from browser i have successful connection with server but with android studio is somethings wrong:

```
    W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:80
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
              at org.schools.loginregister.LoginActivity$AsyncLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:103)
              at org.schools.loginregister.LoginActivity$AsyncLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:59)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcdb6f720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe5efebf0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcdb6f720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe5efebf0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcdb6f720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe5efebf0)
```

Comment: Are you running this from an Emulator? Localhost on an emulator **is not** the same as Localhost on your host machine. You may need to refer to port 80 of your host machine's IP.

Comment: Try to type address of your computer in your local network.

Comment: Can you provide more details ?

Comment: @MichaelDodd thank you! i did that and now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Emulator is, for all intents and purposes, its own device much like a physical phone or tablet. As a result, the emulator has its own internal web server running to provide internal services. `localhost` on the emulator **does not** point to the same web server as `localhost` on your host machine.

In order to access a WAMP server that is running on your host machine, you will need to open up port 80 on your host machine and use your host machine's IP address to connect. The emulator uses Network Address Translation to access your network via its host, so it should be able to access any other network device that your host can access, including the host itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a php file in www folder where your wamp server situated. In the php file you have the code for connect with app and wampserver. The code look like this

my_data.php----

```
<?php
$HostName = 'localhost:3308';  //MySQL port number is 3308
$HostUser = 'root';
$HostPass = '';
$DatabaseName = 'my_data';
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,
$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
// add your code.
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

In the app you have to connect like below code

```
String HTTP_URL = "http://your pc ip address/my_data.php";
   //your pc ip address like 190.158.43.187
```

You can also see my post
https://www.puskarcoding.com/project/how-to-build-mcq-app-connect-to-wampserver-by-android-studio/